# Dynamically add items to a Context Menu & set Click action

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu

I have a List of strings that is regenerated every 5 seconds. I want to create a Context Menu and set its items dynamically using this list.
The problem is that I don't have even a clue how to do that and manage the Click action for every item generated (which should use the same method with different parameter DoSomething("item_name")).

How should I do this?

Thanks for your time.
Best regards.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, you can clear the items from the context menu with:

```
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Clear();
```

You can add an item by calling:

```
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(myString);
```

The context menu has an ItemClicked event.  Your handler could look like so:

```
private void myContextMenuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething(e.ClickedItem.Text);
}
```

Seems to work OK for me.  Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Well, this adds a string... How would one go about adding a MenuItem? That would binding eventhandlers easier

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using a `ToolStripMenuItem` object:

```
//////////// Create a new "ToolStripMenuItem" object:
ToolStripMenuItem newMenuItem= new ToolStripMenuItem();

//////////// Set a name, for identification purposes:
newMenuItem.Name = "nameOfMenuItem";

//////////// Sets the text that will appear in the new context menu option:
newMenuItem.Text = "This is another option!";

//////////// Add this new item to your context menu:
myContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(newMenuItem);
```

Inside the `ItemClicked` event of your `myContextMenuStrip`, you can check which option has been chosen (*based on the name property of the menu item*)

```
private void myContextMenuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripItem item = e.ClickedItem;

    //////////// This will show "nameOfMenuItem":
    MessageBox.Show(item.Name, "And the clicked option is...");
}
```